# How to get rid of excessive spacing in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This morning I started up eclipse and one of my projects has a format that has ridiculously large spacing-see imgur link attached.

[image]

How do I return this to a regular spacing?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look: http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/eclipse-extra-spaces.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Double click this option and it sorts it!

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try `CTRL + SHIFT + F`

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's issue. While `CTRL + SHIFT + F` formats the actual code and can be used to remove white space in code, the OP's issue is that eclipse is enlarging the space between the lines of code, not adding extra white space. If you look, the line numbers are also spread apart. `CTRL + SHIFT + F` will have no effect on the above code.